# Are "not in" and "is not" both operators? If so, are they in any way different than "not x in.." and "not x is.."?

Tags: python

I've always preferred these:

```
not 'x' in 'abc'
not 'x' is 'a'
```

(assuming, of course that everyone knows `in` and `is` out-prioritize `not` -- I probably should use parentheses) over the more (English) grammatical:

```
'x' not in 'abc'
'x' is not 'a'
```

but didn't bother to think why until I realized they do not make syntactical sense

```
'x' == not 'a'
'x' not == 'a'
```

both of course throw a syntax error.

so I figured they were both two-word operators.  However, the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html) only references `is not` and makes no mention of `not in` as an operator.  Am I perhaps misinterpreting the syntax?

If they both are operators, then are they at all different (even subtlety) from their non-grammatical counterparts?

If they are the same, then why do they exist?  It seems to be impious to the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) (.."one -- and preferably only one -- obvious way"..)

I apologize if this has been discussed to death already, I just had little luck finding it with search terms like "is not".

Comment: +1: It's good that the question references a document.  -1: It references the `operator` module, not the language document itself.

Comment: True, I should have kept looking, but I just didn't expect a standard library would be incomplete.

Comment: @bpowah: "I just didn't expect a standard library would be incomplete"  I don't understand that expectation.  What do you mean by "complete"?  And where did you get this expectation?  What other languages have built-in libraries that meet your standard of "completeness"?  Do you have an example or a reference?

Comment: I expected each of these: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#summary to be represented as a function in `operator` summarized here: http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions  The first line of the `operator` documentation states that it has a function "corresponding to the intrinsic operators of Python."  If `not in` is an intrinsic operator then it is incomplete by it's own standard, not mine.  However, I'd be happy to share my personal definition of "completeness" over a beer some time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the python 2.6.4 docs at: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html
>

> The operator not in is defined to have
>   the inverse true value of in.
>
> The operators is and is not test for
>   object identity: x is y is true if and
>   only if x and y are the same object. x
>   is not y yields the inverse truth
>   value.

eg: "x not in y" is exactly the same as "not x in y" and "x is not y" is the same as "not x is y".

"x not == y" doesn't parse, but "x != y" does, so there's an equivalence there too ...

HTH.

Answer (score 7):

It's easy to check if there's any difference, with the [dis](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html?highlight=dis#module-dis) module:

```
>>> dis.dis(compile('not a in b','','exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
              6 COMPARE_OP               7 (not in)
              9 POP_TOP             
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(compile('a not in b','','exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
              6 COMPARE_OP               7 (not in)
              9 POP_TOP             
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

See? The awkward first form (who often confuses those who can't immediately tell the relative priority of `not` and `in` operators) gets compiled into exactly the same bytecode as the can't-confuse-anybody second for, with the single `not in` operator.  Similarly:

```
>>> dis.dis(compile('not a is b','','exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
              6 COMPARE_OP               9 (is not)
              9 POP_TOP             
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(compile('a is not b','','exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
              6 COMPARE_OP               9 (is not)
              9 POP_TOP             
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

both these forms -- the goofy, confusing first one, and the elegant second one -- compare to exactly the same code, and both use the `is not` operator.

Of course there's no good reason to use the forms that can confuse the reader (unless you *like* to set traps for those who read your code!-), but in terms of execution semantics and speed there's no difference whatsoever.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to see!  Thank You.  I guess I still feel a little uneasy about two-word operators for some reason (would have preferred `not_in`), but I'm definitely going to start using them now that they make sense to me and are much more readable.

Answer (score 2):

The remainder of your question has been answered above, but I'll address the last question: the Zen of Python bit.

"There should only be one way to do it" isn't mean't in a mathematical sense. If it were, there'd be no `!=` operator, since that's just the inversion of `==`. Similarly, no `and` and `or` --- you can, after all, just use a single `nand` command. There is a limit to the "one way" mantra: there should only be one high-level way of doing it. Of course, that high-level way can be decomposed --- you can write your own `math.tan`, and you never need to use `urllib` --- `socket` is always there for you. But just as `urllib.open` is a higher-level encapsulation of raw `socket` operations, so `not in` is a higher-level encapsulation of `not` and `in`. That's a bit banal, you might say. But you use `x != y` instead of `not (x == y)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your documentation reference is nothing to do with syntax. [Try this](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#notin). Both `is not` and `not in` are two-word operators.

Answer (score 0):

`x in a` tests whether the element x is in a (which in this case would probably be a list or a string or some such) and returns `True` if it is.

`x not in a` is similar, but returns `False` if x is in a.

On the other hand, `x is not a` is analogous to `x != a` and `not x is a`.

And like you said, x == not 5 will give you an error of sorts